# What is the server command to give my named wolf more health in Minecraft version 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What would the Minecraft Server/cheat command be to give a wolf more health. I know that you can make a named wolf invincible, but I'd prefer to just increase the wolf's health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly, I don't think it is possible to increase an already spawned mob's health without help of a world editor.

Indirectly, you can give yourself a custom, infinite duration healthboost-effect splash potion with the following command from the [Minecraft Tools potion generator](https://minecraft.tools/en/potion.php):

```
/give @p minecraft:splash_potion{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:21,Amplifier:127,Duration:2147483647}],display:{Name:"\"Custom Potion\""}}
```

This is a command that will give you a splash potion with the max level of health boost, being 128, with each level increasing the mob's health by 2 hearts (4 points of health).

---

And although this part probably doesn't answer your question, I'll include it for broadness, you can also just summon a wolf with more health using this command:

```
/summon Wolf ~0 ~1 ~0 {Attributes:[{Name:generic.maxHealth,Base:500}],Health:500.0f}
```

With "500" being an adjustable number, though bear in mind that 1024 is the maximum amount of health points a given mob can have.

Comment: Although this doesn't tackle exactly what I wanted I tthink it might be my only option and it still works well. That potion generator is a lot of fun!

Answer (score 3):

The command

```
/effect give @e[name="name of your dog here"] health_boost 1000000 255
```

would give your wolf an exorbitant amount of health.

You can add other effects, such as resistance to make it unkillable, strength to make it kill nearly everything, etc., etc.